# ASP.NET Core - cannot convert from 'Customers.Response.GetCustomersResponseDto' to 'PagingDto'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, epplus, asp.net-core-6.0

In my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API application, I am implementing server-side Excel download (export) using the EPPlus package.

This is my code:

Response:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public bool Successful { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public Response(int statusCode, bool success, string msg, T data)
    {
        Data = data;
        Successful = success;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Message = msg;
    }

    public Response()
    {
    }

    public static Response<T> Fail(string errorMessage, int statusCode = 404)
    {
        return new Response<T> { Successful = false, Message = errorMessage, StatusCode = statusCode };
    }

    public static Response<T> Success(string successMessage, T data, int statusCode = 200)
    {
        return new Response<T> { Successful = true, Message = successMessage, Data = data, StatusCode = statusCode };
    }

    public override string ToString() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}
```

`PagingDto`:

```
public class PagingDto
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }    
}
```

`PageResult`:

```
public class PageResult<T>
{
    public T PageItems { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public int PreviousPage { get; set; }
}
```

Then after the paginator I have the model and DTO, Customer and `GetCustomersResponseDto`:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class GetCustomersResponseDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Repository:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    return _customers.OrderBy(b => b.CreatedAt);;
}
```

The repository is implemented in the service as shown below.

Service:

```
public async Task<Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<GetCustomersResponseDto>>>> GetAllCustomersAsync(PagingDto pagenator)
{
    var customers =  await _unitOfWork.Customers.GetAllCustomers();
    var customersList = await customers.PaginationAsync<Customer, GetCustomersResponseDto>(pagenator.PageSize,pagenator.PageNumber, _mapper);
    var response = new Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<GetUsersResponseDto>>>();

    if(customersList != null)
    {
        response.Data = customersList;
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Succeeded = true;

        return response;
    }

    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    response.Succeeded = false;
    response.Message = "No customer exist at this time";

    return response;
}

private Response<bool> ConvertAllCustomerExcel(IEnumerable<GetCustomersResponseDto> reports)
{
     byte[] fileContents;
     ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

     using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
     {
         // Set author for excel file
         package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Japhet";
         // Set title for excel file
         package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Customer List";
         var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");                 
         var currentRow = 1;               

         worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 1].Value = "First Name";
         worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 2].Value = "Last Name";
         worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 3].Value = "Email";
         worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 4].Value = "UserName";                

         // Style for Excel 
         worksheet.DefaultColWidth = 16;
         worksheet.Cells.Style.Font.Size = 16; 

         // Export Data from Table customers
         foreach (var report in reports)
         {
             currentRow++;
             worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 1].Value = report.FirstName;
             worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 2].Value = report.LastName;
             worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 3].Value = report.Email;
             worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 4].Value = report.UserName;
         }                 

         fileContents = package.GetAsByteArray();
     }             

     if (fileContents == null || fileContents.Length == 0)
     {
         return NoContent();
     }             

     return File(
         fileContents: fileContents,
         contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
         fileDownloadName: "Customers.xlsx");
}
```

Finally I imported `ConvertAllCustomerExcel`:

```
public async Task<Response<string>> ExportToCustomersExcel(GetCustomersResponseDto filter)
{
    var response = new Response<string>();
    var customers =  _unitOfWork.Customers.GetAllCustomersAsync(filter);
    return this.ConvertAllCustomerExcel(customers);

        response.Data = "Successfully Downloaded";
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Succeeded = true;

    return response;
}
```

Kindly note that:

```
public async Task<Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<GetCustomersResponseDto>>>> GetAllCustomersAsync(PagingDto pagenator)
```

I didn't include the paginator in Excel download (Export) because Excel doesn't need it

It works fine, and it displays the paginated data.

But I have issues with the methods to export to Excel.

I got theis error:

Error CS1503   
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Customers.Response.GetCustomersResponseDto' to 'PagingDto'

And it highlights `filter` in:

```
var customers =  _unitOfWork.Customers.GetAllCustomersAsync(filter);
```

How do I resolve these?

Comment: Well, isn't the error explicit? `GetAllCustomersAsync` expects a PagingDto as single parameter but you can see that the variable filter is actually a GetCustomerResponseDto so it couldn't work. I don't really see a similarity between the two classes so I'm not sure what is going here? Did you copy this code from somewhere, did you write it? do you understand what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: @jeromej- Pagingation is in the response of   Task<Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<GetCustomersResponseDto>>>> GetAllCustomersAsync(PagingDto pagenator)  But I didn't include the pagination in the Excel Export because there's is no need for that. Or how else can I do that

Comment: All I can say is that the code you gave us cannot work and, as a matter of fact, does not compile. The method you're trying to call requires to be given a pagingDto object but filter is _not_ that so "ofc" it will not be happy and will not compile. Where do you call ExportToCustomersExcel and why does it receive a GetCustomersResponseDto object? GetCustomersResponseDto contains info about ONE customer. GetAllCustomersAsync retrieves all customers based on a some pagination, not based on a customer info (the filter you're trying to give it).

Answer (score 0):

Please use .AsEnumerable() in the end of your get method:

```
var customers =  _unitOfWork.Customers.GetAllCustomersAsync(filter).AsEnumerable();
```

I will give your output as enumerable.

Comment: filters is still highlighted with this error:    cannot convert from 'Customers.Response.GetCustomersResponseDto' to 'PagingDto'